# How to remove duplicate object array in c# (without using other function or library)

Tags: c#, object

i was tried to code my self a no duplicate object array function.

But it not working.

Somehow it print all the object element

May i know where i am doing it wrong ? I was so confuse why it is not working.

This is my code

```
 using System;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Linq;

 namespace MyApp 
 {
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] mix_arr = new object[8];
            mix_arr[0] = 25;
            mix_arr[1] = "Anna";
            mix_arr[2] = false;
            mix_arr[3] = 25;
            mix_arr[4] = System.DateTime.Now;
            mix_arr[5] = 112.22;
            mix_arr[6] = "Anna";
            mix_arr[7] = false;
            object[] unique_arr = new object[8];
            bool clone = false; // this bool is to check duplicate
            int k = 0; // increment the unique_ arr index

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                clone = false;
                // clone will always set to false 
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                   if(unique_arr[j] == mix_arr[i])
                   { 
                     // if found 2 object element are the same, set clone true                     
                     clone = true; 
                     break;
                   }                           
                }
                if (clone == false)
                {
                    // if no duplicate entry 
                    unique_arr[k++] = mix_arr[i];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ",mix_arr[i]);        
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");         
        }    
    }       
}
```

Comment: You can make it very difficult for yourself by fiddling with arrays. You can also make a list next to it, in which you only add the unique and later convert that back to an array. In C# we usually do the second solution. Because when it comes to micro optimization, it's better to write it in c++. ;-)

Comment: You are actually printing the initial array ( Console.Write("{0} ",mix_arr[i]); ) not the filtered one (unique_arr)

Comment: @AzzyElvul oh ya thanks for pointing that out , but i changed to unique_arr also the same result.

Comment: The problem in that approach is in that the mixed_arr contains a boxed values. In some case you should check the boxed value instead of the value itself.

Comment: @AzzyElvul alright

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen noted that